# Content-Security-Policy: Refused to load the stylesheet

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I have a static website, so I'm inserting my CSP in a `meta` tag at the top of the `head` block of my website:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="base-uri 'self'; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com; manifest-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self'; style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline';>
```

Let's say my website is `example.com`, I get the following error in the console:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://example.com/main.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'".
```

If I remove `style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'` from my CSP, I'm able to load my CSS file just fine (but I get a different error about not loading `script` tags with code in them that React seems to generate).  I'm unsure why the CSP rules `style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com` and `style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'` seem to conflict with each other.

I know using `unsafe-inline` is not ideal, but for a static website with no user interaction, I believe it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

style-src-elem takes precedence over style-src when the browser has implemented support for it. When you define just 'unsafe-inline' as the only source, only inline scripts are allowed, you can not load files from any location. When you remove style-src-elem it falls back to style-src which allows loading from 'self' (same origin). The script file issue doesn't have enough details to comment on.